# Does Magica De Spell's magic have any known limits?

Tags: ducktales, donald-duck

Does Magica De Spell's magic have any known limits that are consistently used throughout the Duckverse?

I recall some comic stating she can't produce money, but I also recall another one where she does. (I will link them when I find them). But there doesn't seem to be anything consistent where she cannot get something. (The only thing she can never do is get the Number One Dime, but even that is due to her incompetence, not to limits of her magic.)

So, is there any known, consistently adhered to, limits to Magica's magic? Or do the comic writers just make it up as they go along?

Comment: I'm not sure about the original canon by Carl Barks (so I don't write this as an answer), but in many comics she is vulnerable to garlic. In its presence, she usually faints and loses her powers

Comment: It's not necessarily consistent power levels, but it was indicated in the original cartoons that giving her access to magical artifacts of significant power (like Scrooge's Lucky Dime) can give her a significant power-up.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly, since *Ducktales* (2017) is still ongoing, this could be later disproven, but classically, all her power has been via artifacts; note that once the amulet/scepter cracked, she had nothing to attack Scrooge with and had to retreat. It's why she's after the Number One Dime after all.

Comment: This is a great answer. If you would add proof and citations how all her powers are from artifacts (comic or cartoon screenshots, and/or internet articles) I'll give you a 100 bounty.